# Electric charge and cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

An electric charge is distributed with a uniform volume density $\rho$ in a cylinder with a radius $R$ and an infinite length.

Our professor said the following: By symmetry, the electric field is perpendicular to the axis of the cylinder

That's something I cannot grasp. Since the charge is distributed with uniformity, isn't the electric field *parallel* to the axis of the cylinder?

Also, when we apply Gauss's law we get

$$\int \vec{E}.d \vec{S}= \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$

Why is that so?

Comment: If the cylinder were finite in length, then there could be a component parallel to the cylinder axis near the ends.  However, since it is infinite in length and the charges have already done work to uniformly distribute themselves throughout the volume, there can be no electric field along the cylinder axis.  If there were one, then it would do work on $\rho$ and make it no longer uniform...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gauss's law in integral form is better used to find the field whenever there is a symmetry in the problem. But to make the concept clear, I'm going to use the differential form, which tells the exact meaning as the integral form. The Gauss's law in differential form reads:

$$∇.E=ρ/ϵ_0$$

where $ρ$ is the volume charge density. Now observe this equation. It tells us that the electric field diverging from a volume charge distribution depends on the amount of charge residing in the volume. i.e., the electric field is diverging out from the volume (the region inside the cylinder where you have the charge distribution).

This diverging field will be perpendicular to the surface enclosing the volume, as you can easily imagine. Of course, the electric field also diverges through the ends. But we could totally ignore that component (something parallel to the axis of the cylinder) if we take an infinitely long cylinder, which is exactly your problem (since in the case of an infinitely long cylinder, we don't need to worry about the end sides). It is still not a problem, if you consider the end points also. It's because when you use the integral formula, the

$$E.dS$$

term vanishes since the field and the area vector points in the same direction. So only the radial component contributes to the net field. This came as a consequence of symmetry.

So the electric field is radial, which means that the field points perpendicular to all the points on the curved surface.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you put a positive test charge in the region of the cylinder or inside it which way would the force on the charge be?  This is the direction of the electric field.
If you think that it parallel to the axis can you explain why the positive test charge would move one way rather than the other?  There is no difficulty with direction if you make the perpendicular choice for the electric field.